# facebook like button shows tens of thousands of likes

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have embedded facebook like button into my application:

```
<li id="fb-wr" class="header-bar-item">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=777";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</li>
```

Now the problem is that it shows incorrect number of likes - currently it's 93k and growing with each day. I've tried debugging with [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and here what it showed me:

- Admins And App ID Missing
  fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing.
  These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story
  that generates a high click-through rate.
- Like Button Tag Missing
  og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag is necessary for
  Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high
  click-through rate.
- Like Button Tag Missing
  og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed
  story that generates a high click-through rate.
- Like Button Tag Missing
  og:image is missing. The og:image meta tag is necessary for
  Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high
  click-through rate.

But these are warning and not errors. I don't think that any of them causes the weird count. Console shows no errors as well.
So what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you really use appId=777 ?

Comment: No, this is fake appId. I use my real appId :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook like button stores likes per page

```
data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"
```

tells facebook that this button is for page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

this should be replaced with your url